# Hilbert triples

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I apologize if this is a trivial matter for the analysts out there, but I looked this up in a number of books (e.g., H. Brezis, J. Wloka) and could not find a satisfying discussion, one that would settle my question.

Recall that a Hilbert (or Gelfand) triple consists of two Hilbert spaces $V, H$ such that one has continuous, injective and dense inclusions $V \hookrightarrow H \hookrightarrow V^*$.

Given one such triple, one can define the Sobolev space $W \equiv W^{1,2}([0, 1]; V, V^*)$, which is the space of all functions $u : [0, 1] \rightarrow V$ having a weak derivative $u' : [0, 1] \rightarrow V^*$.

Finally, one has the Sobolev embedding theorem, saying that $W$ embeds continuously in $C([0, 1]; H)$.

**My question:** since $H$ does not play any role in the definition of $W$, why is the Sobolev embedding theorem stated in that way?

It seems to me that $V \hookrightarrow V \hookrightarrow V^*$ is always a Hilbert triple, and then one gets for free that $W$ actually embeds in $C([0, 1]; V)$, which seems to be a stronger statement. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: $V$ and $H$ are not given the same topology, and $V\subset H$ will not be closed with the topology of $H$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I'm sorry, but I don't understand the relation between my question and what you said. I'm not requiring that $V$ is a subspace of $H$, just that it embeds continuously. Could you elaborate?

Comment: OK, but then via the embedding, we can think of $V$ as a (non-closed) subspace of $H$, and my comment was that then $V$ has a stronger topology than $H$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I agree, and this is why I asked this question. It would seem that one can strengthen the conclusion of the Sobolev embedding by applying it to the triple $V \hookrightarrow V \hookrightarrow V^*$, where $V$ now plays the role of $H$. This gives the stronger statement that $W$ embeds in $C([0, 1]; V)$, does it not?

Comment: Put differently, if you embed $V\mapsto V$ trivially, with the identity, then $V^*$ is just $V$ itself, by the Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: $V^*$ is built in relation to $H$. In your situation, $V^*=V$, which is not too helpful.

Comment: You might get the stronger statement that W embeds in C([0,1]; V), but then how do you know there are enough interesting things in W? (Also, I second @AndrásBátkai's comment)

Comment: @AndrásBátkai Ah, so this is my mistake: I assumed $V^*$ was just the dual of $V$. So what you and Yemon are saying is that $W$ _does_ depend on $H$. I see. Thank you.

Comment: $V^*$ is the dual of $V$, but we emphasize the relation of these spaces to $H$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling If $V^*$ is just the dual of $V$, I don't see how $H$ enters into the definition of $W$.What András and Yemon were saying led me to think that the construction of $W$ does depend on $H$, because $V^*$ itself depends on $H$. So I don't understand which one is right.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Oh, maybe you meant the dual of the image of $V$, as a subspace of $H$? Is that what $V^*$ is supposed to mean, above? That would depend on $H$, ofc.

Comment: $V^*$ as a Hilbert space does not depend on $H$ (and I don't think that's what Andras and Yemon said). [In fact, if your spaces are separable, there's only one Hilbert space anyway, up to isomorphism.] We don't just consider the spaces in isolation, though, we set up the embeddings you mentioned. The Wikipedia article has a pretty clear summary, I think.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I'm sorry to insist on this, but I have to be honest here. You say $V^*$ does not depend on $H$, so let's accept that. Does $W$, as constructed above, depend on $H$ or not? If not, then there seems to be a trivial way to strenghten the conclusion of the Sobolev embedding. I don't think this should be so, but I'm struggling to see why it does not follow from what I said in the body of the question.

Comment: I can't answer that because I'm not sufficiently familiar with the definition of your $W$. However, let me give you a silly example that may (or may not) illuminate your difficulty: Let $K=\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$, $L=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. Then you can say that $K\cong L$, or you could embed $L$ into $K$ as a proper subspace. What I'm trying to say is that we have spaces AND maps, and one and the same space can take various roles.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I see your point, but where precisely are these maps relevant when it comes to defining $W$ is what I'm missing here, I think.

Comment: I think the **question should be closed** since it arises from the OP not having "done his homework". The OP should read e.g. Wloka's account (in the PDE book) on Gelfand triples *carefully*. Then it becomes clear that the definition of OP's space $W$ indeed depends on $H$ . More precisely, it depends on the Hilbert (inner product) space $H$ and the "finer" inner product of $V$ defined on the *vector* subspace $V$ of $H$ . It is only loose language to express a Gelfand triple as " $V\hookrightarrow H\hookrightarrow V^*$ ".